# subprocess.Popen ssh tunnel launches 2nd process which requires answering a prompt with a pin

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, subprocess, popen, tunnel

I am creating an ssh tunnel using subprocess.Popen. However to successfully create this tunnel I am using a Yubikey which requires a pin to release the keys for successful authentication, built in with ssh config. Code below is as far as I can get.

```
def launch_tunnel(self):
    try:
        enterpin = getpass.getpass()
        bytepin = str.encode(enterpin)
        launchtunnel = subprocess.Popen('ssh tunnel command', 
                                        shell=True, 
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE
                                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate(input=bytepin)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

When I run it I get the following 2 prompts.

```
Password:
Enter PIN for 'PIV_II (PIV Card Holder pin)':
```

First one being getpass.getpass() and the second one being another process which requires the Yubikey Pin. It's clear that .communicate() is not working here and from what I can tell it's because the ssh process spawns another process(the pin prompt) that requires the pin for ssh authentication.

Is there anyway to set the pin prior using something like getpass and pass it directly to the 2nd process. Currently this 2nd process(pin prompt) is interrupting the rest of my application so I would like to control it?

Answer (score 0):

I found part of the solution. Using communicate() without anything in () halts the process at the prompt so I do not need to implement getpass before launching subprocess. It has given me another issue but I will take that to a new thread.

```
launchtunnel = subprocess.Popen(checktunnelexists[1], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
launchtunnel.communicate()[0]
```